# Method lists does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

[image]I am trying to populate my select box from DB with this approach

```
{!! Form::select('worktypes', $worktypes->lists('name'), null, ['class' => 'col-md-2 form-control', 'required', 'placeholder' => '--auswählen']) !!}
```

But method lists() doesn't exist anymore in Laravel 5.3

Is there some other method for this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I just found out:

Method `lists()` is deprecated in Laravel v5.2^

It is renamed to:

```
pluck()
```

The method signature remains the same.

[Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade#upgrade-5.2.0)

search for `Deprecations` on that link

---

Update:
just in case that link ever dies or page changes, this is what was on it:

> Deprecations The following features are deprecated in 5.2 and will be
> removed in the 5.3 release in June 2016:
>
> The lists method on the Collection, query builder and Eloquent query
> builder objects has been renamed to pluck. The method signature
> remains the same.